# I'm using qt to design a program and need help because my code is not DRY

Tags: c++, qt

I know that I need to use `QObject::children, but I'm struggling to word it right to find a video online that explains it in a way I can understand, obviously because I don't fully understand what it is I'm looking for.

Basically I have 4 lineEdits and 2 comboBoxes and at the end I have a pushButton. This is repeated exactly 20 times.

Now my program works fine, but I know there is a better way, as I explained in the title my code IS NOT DRY at all and currently looks like this example below:

mainWindow.cpp file

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton1_clicked()
{
    ui->lineEdit1->clear();
    ui->lineEdit2->clear();
    ui->comboBox1->setCurrentIndex(0);
    ui->lineEdit3->clear();
    ui->lineEdit4->clear();
    ui->comboBox2->setCurrentIndex(0);
}
```

mainWindow.h file

```
void on_button1_clicked();
```

The above is then repeated 20 times.

The project is basically a register. With 6 columns Name, Type (comboBox), Age, Time in, Time out, Paid(comboBox) and a button.

At the top I have two counters. one is for Total space and the other is for Available.

If name is occupied then Available displays Total space minus 1.
When the reset button is clicked Available obviously adds 1.

I have read [QObject Class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#) but I'm a slow, slightly dim learner and really need some help in demonstrating, showing or given a tutorial on how I can use this to DRY up my code.

I apologize if this has been covered before but as I said I don't fully understand what it is I'm trying to look for and I have no idea how to take the information from the link above and put it into my project.

I'm using QT-Creator 4 on a Linux host.

Comment: So your code works, you just want to find a better way of implementing it? Might want to try: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ this is no where near a replica of that not even close please re-read what i have put because the link you shared doesnt have buttons or comboBoxes just text

Comment: I think the point of it is that you're saying you repeat it 20 times... but if nothing is changing, you can use a loop. And if something is changing, you didnt specify it in your question.

Comment: because i dont fully understand it myself it isnt a loop. yes the same thing is repeated over and over but im using buttons comboboxes and line edits. From what i have read on his example its no where near to even close as to explaining how to use QObject::children

I even stated I'm slightly dim and slow at learning and he links something miles away. 

Basically its like a register name age then a drop down combo box. 
Once the person leaves you clear it but only that row. There are 20 rows each with its own clear/reset button

Comment: I want to put their values inside an array. That is the quote from the link. I dont need to put there values in an array. My code works fine and does exactly what i want it to do. But its not dry

Comment: @scope The linked dupe shows a number of techniques you can use for repeated UI elements to handle these in a loop. It doesn't matter much if these are comboboxes or lineedit controls. If you aren't able to extrapolate these examples for your particular needs that's your fault, not ours.